# Existe uma forma de saber os nome do Servidor do Banco da Dados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Existe um commando sql que possa informar o servidor e a base de dados em que está sendo executado o select?

Estou a disposição para mais detalhes

Answer (score 4):

Sim. você pode usar o seguinte `select`.

```
select @@SERVERNAME, DB_NAME()
```

Comment: Opa, veleu. Consegui também achar pelo SELECT * FROM sys.servers que além do server mostra os links dos outros servers. Unico problema é que eu gostaria de saber qual o nome do Alias do server. Existe como?

Comment: @EmanuelF, alias do server? Refere-se a DNS ou virtualhost?

Comment: Foi atribuido um nome ao servidor. Temos um nome que aponta para o servidor.

Comment: o `@@SERVERNAME` não trás esse nome?

Comment: Sim, ele trás o nome: SRV1 mas eu tenho atribuido para ele o nome: dbDWserver1